# VBA to CountBlank the top 10 rows of every column (1 to 50)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the below code to work.  I would like to count blank cells for columns 1 to 50 in each worksheet.  The below works, but it counts for the entire column.  How can I change it to only count the first 10 rows in each column and if they are all blank, then change the column width to 1?

Many thanks

```
    For j = 1 To 50
        Blanks = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Worksheet.Columns(j))
        If Blanks > 10 Then
            ws.Columns(j).ColumnWidth = 1
        End If
    Next j
```

Comment: did you find any answers here helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to check the first 10 rows you need to specify this in your `CountBlank` function. Your `CountBlank(Worksheet.Columns(j))` is counting the entire column.

Also, your `If Blanks > 10 Then` will never evaluate to `True` as you only want to count `10` rows. I've changed that expression to `If Blanks = 10`.

```
Sub countTest()

    Dim wks As Worksheet

    Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For j = 1 To 50
        Blanks = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(wks.Range(Cells(1, j), Cells(10, j)))
        If Blanks = 10 Then
            wks.Columns(j).ColumnWidth = 1
        End If
    Next j

    Set wks = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked very well.  Thanks for that and for spotting the other mistake.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
For i = 1 To 50
    k=0
    For j = 1 to 10
        If Activesheet.Cells(j,i).Value = "" Then
            k=k+1
        End If
    Next j

    If k = 10 Then
        Activesheet.Columns(i).ColumnWidth = 1
    End If
Next i
```

Let me know if there are any issues with it.